Involution map on real stiefel manifold orientation preserving?
We have an involution map on real Stiefel manifold $V_{n,2}$.  $(v,w) \rightarrow (-v,-w)$. I want to know if this map is orientation preserving. n is odd here. My guess is, it is. As, Projective Stiefel Manifolds $PV_{n,2}$ are orientable for n odd. But, I don't know if any orientation comes from Stiefel manifold. I could not find any direct reference.

This map is  homotopic to the identity, and therefore preserve orientation : if $(u,v)$ is a pair of orthogonal unit vectors, set $F_t (u,v)= (\cos (t)u+\sin (t)  v, -\sin (t) u+\cos (t) v)$. For $t=\pi$, $F_t(u,v)=(-u-,v)$

I don't think those two vectors are orthogonal.

Sorry, silly mistake. It is fine now. Thank You.
